# Is there a way to "watch" a variable in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Basically, I want to add a breakpoint every time a given closure variable is changed.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's currently a way to *directly* watch variables, but if you can put the closure variable in an object, then you can use `Object.observe()` to observe that object for changes. (Object.observe can only observe objects) 
This requires you to have Experimental Javascript enabled - `chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony`.

```
(function(){
  var holder = { 
    watchedVariable: "something"
  };

  Object.observe(holder, function (changes) {
    // returns an array of objects(changes)

    if ( changes[0].name === "watchedVariable" ) {
      debugger;
    }

  });

})()
```

Comment: Enabled experimental JS, relaunched chrome, and `Object.observe is not a function`

Comment: @Kirkland Object.observe is deprecated. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258502/why-has-object-observe-been-deprecated for reason and alternatives