# What is the alternative of Object.observe as it is already been deprecated

Tags: javascript, object.observe

As O.o is already been deprecated what are the other options we have to observe the properties of a Javascript Object.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258502/why-has-object-observe-been-deprecated

Comment: getter and setter

Comment: Quote from MDN: `However, this API has been deprecated and removed from browsers. You can use the more general Proxy object instead.`

Comment: @Shilly: Proxy is not yet supported in IE.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the mdn documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe

> The Object.observe() method was used for asynchronously observing the
>   changes to an object. It provided a stream of changes in the order in
>   which they occur. However, this API has been deprecated and removed
>   from browsers. You can use the more general [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object instead.

Comment: `Proxy` is not supported by IE

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with getters and setters and alternatively, in a browser with support for Proxies, you can write a more generic solution.
[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258502/why-has-object-observe-been-deprecated)

Comment: The issue is that you have to plug into the object chain. There is no way to observe changes in a "readymade" object that is parsed from JSON for example..

Comment: Implementing this in getters and setters is a lot of boilerplate or 'monkey coding' which leaves technical debt and 'too much code' issues (=more time, more bugs, more time to read, more cost, no more value [than an alternative]). It is a subtle and often unnoticed thief of IT budget.