# How do I watch a window.variable change with a callback?

Tags: javascript

I have a global variable and its type is *String*:

```
window.my_global_var = 'string';
```

It might be changed by some external-loaded JavaScript files or an AJAX request. So I want to watch it and invoke a callback when it's updated.

I searched a while but found Object.observe is already deprecated. I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36258688/1661640) but it is better used to observe an object, not a String window.variable.

The worst approach would be using a `setInterval` to watch it but I guess it's too stupid.

Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: May the global variablbe a function? Or maybe you can define it using `Object.defineProperty` with a getter?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Object.defineProperties` on `window`:

```
function onValueUpdate(my_global_var) {
   // Some arbitrary logic you want to execute on callback
   console.log(`my_global_var was updated: ${my_global_var}`);
}

Object.defineProperties(window, {
    _my_global_var: {
        value: 'string',
        writable: true
    },
    my_global_var: {
        get: function() {
            return this._my_global_var;
        },
        set: function(val) {
            this._my_global_var = val;
            onValueUpdate(this._my_global_var);
        }
    }
});

window.my_global_var = 'New string';
```

When you access `window.my_global_var` it behaves exactly as the property of type `String` would. But when you set it you can adjust it to use any additional logic.

Function `onValueUpdate` needs to be public (or you can use a public method instead).

[There’s a warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42192333/11663995) against this approach in the answer you’ve found though:

> I'd not go with getters/setters solution - it's complicated, not scalable and not maintainable.

So if you need scalability you probably should look for some library that can do that. Otherwise this should work just as well.

Comment: One minor addition, there's no need for `onValueUpdate` to be global, it just has to be in scope for the setter.

Comment: This is a nice little util. Our application has a bunch of stuff assigned to the window, which we would like to remove. Now we can trace where the global object is used and fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the global object in a proxy with a [`set` handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set). You would need to pass the proxy around your program, rather than relying implicitly on the global object, however.

```js
const handler = {
  set(obj, prop, value) {
    if (prop === 'foo')
      console.log(`Property updated with value: ${value}!`)
    return Reflect.set(...arguments)
  }
};

const proxy = new Proxy(window, handler);
proxy.foo = 1 // "Property updated with value: 1!"
proxy.bar = 2 

console.log(foo) // 1
console.log(bar) // 2
```